# Map foreign key JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have a table `Customer` with these fields

1. customer_id (PK)
2. customer_name
3. customer_surname

I also have some other tables that container a FK pointing to some customer.. For example `Table1` has these fields:

1. table1_id (PK)
2. table1_col1
3. table1_customer_id (FK references customer_id in `Customer`)

`Table2` has these fields:

1. table2_id (PK)
2. table2_col1
3. table2_customer_id (FK references customer_id in `Customer`)

The list of tables referencing the customers in the `Customer` table can potentially grow and here is where I struggle with the JPA mapping.

I have an Entity `Customer` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private String customerId;
    
    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String customerName;
    
    @Column(name = "customer_surname")
    private String customerSurname;
    
    // getters & setters
}
```

but now I don't know how to map the FKs for the other tables. How I would I map for example the `Table1`?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1)
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "table1_id")
    private Long table1Id;
    
    @Column(name = "table1_col1)
    private String table1Col1;
    
    //private Long table1CustomerId;    how can I make this a FK?
    
    // getters & setters
}
```

The constraints are that each table (`Table1`, .., `TableN`) can have at most one customer, but each customer can be in any of the `Table1`, .., `TableN`.

Thank you

Comment: I encourage you to [take a look at relationships annotations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_entity_relationships.htm).

Comment: Indeed, why not a relationship? It would be something like `@ManyToOne private Customer customer` in the `TableN` classes. Could be made bidirectional, by adding the relevant fields in the `Customer` or remain unidirectional with no changes to the `Customer`. JPA knows to create a FK.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I think I will keep it unidirectional for now using the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "table1_customer_id")
private Customer customer;
```